# Sesion de un portal net 4.5 invocado desde un iframe por un Portal Net6

Tags: sesiones, net, framework, .net-6.0, migracion

Estoy migrando un portal net 4.5 a net 6. Pero por temas de tiempo se quiere hacer que desde el portal net 6 se llame desde un iframe a opciones del portal net4.5.
Se que lo recomendable seria migrar todo el tiempo pero por falta de tiempo y recursos se quiere salir de esta manera.

El tema es que el portal net4.5 realiza un login y guarda los datos de sesiones en unos claim.

Ya me contacte con soporte de microsoft y me dijeron que por temas de incompatibilidad no se puede hacer de esa manera.

Otra opcion que se me ocurrio fue guardar los datos en una session de lado del net4.5 pero cuando quiero leer la sesion me sale que esta es null.

Alguna idea para parchar este problema.

```
public string ObtieneValorClaim(ClaimsIdentity identity, string key)
        {
            string resultado = "";
            LoginNet6 loginInfo = new LoginNet6();

            var model = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginNet6"];

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginNet6"] != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginNet6"] is LoginNet6)
            {
                loginInfo = (LoginNet6)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginNet6"];                
            }

            switch (key)
            {
                case ClaimTypes.Name:
                    if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name))
                    {
                        resultado = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = loginInfo.Name;
                    }
                    break;

                case ClaimTypes.Role:
                    if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role))
                    {
                        resultado = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = loginInfo.Role;
                    }
                    break;

                case ClaimTypes.Locality:
                    if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Locality))
                    {
                        resultado = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Locality).Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = loginInfo.Locality;
                    }
                    break;

                case ClaimTypes.Rsa:
                    if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Rsa))
                    {
                        resultado = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Rsa).Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = loginInfo.Rsa;
                    }
                    break;

                case ClaimTypes.Dns:
                    if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Dns))
                    {
                        resultado = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Dns).Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = loginInfo.Dns;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    // Tipo de claim no reconocido
                    break;
            }

            return resultado;
        }
```

Comment: En todos mis años como desarrollador en .net, dependiendo de la arquitectura del sistema, la migración podría ser sencilla como podría ser compleja. Lo que estás queriendo hacer, es técnicamente poco probable que funcione o sencillamente imposible que funcione. Espero haya algún otro dotnetero que me corrija en caso esté en un error. Mi recomendación es hablar con los que tomaron la decisión de migrar y exigirles más tiempo y si no hay tiempo suficiente, no hay migración. Saludos.

Comment: Existe varias formas de resolver el problema: Suponiendo que un usuario se logea con las mismas claves en ambos sistemas, en el login del .net6 agregas un iframe oculto al login del 4.5 y metes los datos con javascript, así te logeas en los 2 sistemas al mismo tiempo. (2)  No usas iframes, y en el .net haces una especie de proxy al .net 4.5 usando webclient o httpclient. (3) En el .net4.5 creas una nueva forma de autenticación basada en tokens y se lo pasas por la URL del iframe, y así muchas más, pero es imposible dar una respuesta con los datos que has proporcionado